# HTML/JS Google Maps API for reviews is showing only 5 reviews

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-reviews

I am writing a website in which I need to extract data from google reviews. I used the Google Maps library to get the places but it only returns 5 reviews (the place I am getting the data from has over 70)

reviews.html

```
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>


function fetchGoogleReviews(placeId) {
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
  var request = {
      placeId: placeId,
      fields: ['name', 'rating', 'reviews']
  };

  function fetchReviews(nextPageToken) {
      request.pageToken = nextPageToken || "";
      service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              var allReviews = place.reviews || []; // Initialize empty array if no reviews in first response
              if (nextPageToken) {
                  // Append reviews from subsequent requests
                  allReviews = allReviews.concat(reviewsView.reviews); // Replace reviewsView.reviews with your existing array to store all reviews
              }

              const stars = place.rating;
              document.getElementById("stars").setAttribute("data-star", stars);
              document.getElementById("stars-text").innerHTML = `${stars} stars`;

              const comments = document.createElement("div");
              comments.id = `reviews-number`;
              comments.innerHTML = `${allReviews.length} reviews`;

              const googleReviewsView = document.createElement("a");
              googleReviewsView.href = `url`
              const googleReviews = document.createElement("img")
              googleReviews.src = `/media/assets/google-reviews.png`
              googleReviewsView.appendChild(googleReviews)
              comments.appendChild(googleReviewsView);
              reviewsView.appendChild(comments);

              displayReviews(allReviews);
              // Check for next page token and make another request if available
              if (place.next_page_token) {
                    fetchReviews(place.next_page_token);
            } 

          } else {
              console.error('Error fetching place details:', status);
          }
      });
  }

  fetchReviews(); // Initial request without nextPageToken
}


    // Function to display reviews on the webpage
    function displayReviews(reviews) {
        for(let i = 0; i < reviews.length; i++){
                reviewsView.appendChild(newReview(reviews[i]))
        }
    }
    // Call the fetchGoogleReviews function with your business's place ID
    fetchGoogleReviews('PLACEID');
```

what can I do to get all the reviews?